# Line chart displaying 'NaN' date format - issue

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am writing to seek help, in how can I format the date to the following format (dd-mm-yyyy) instead of what is currently showing in the output below:

[image]

I have added in a date parser in the javascript below and I am still unsure, why I am getting this format.  Please advice.

```
    function drawVisualization(dataValues, chartTitle, columnNames, categoryCaption) {
        if (dataValues.length < 1)
            return;

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[0]);
        data.addColumn('number', columnNames.split(',')[1]);
        data.addColumn('string', columnNames.split(',')[2]);
        data.addColumn('datetime', columnNames.split(',')[3]);

        for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

            var date = new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].Date.substr(6), 10));

            data.addRow([dataValues[i].ColumnName, dataValues[i].Value, dataValues[i].Type, date]);
        }

        var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'dd MM yyyy' });
        var line = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'LineChart',
            'containerId': 'PieChartContainer',
            'options': {
                'width': 950,
                'height': 450,
                'legend': 'right',
                'hAxis': {
                    'format': "dd-MM-yyyy",
                    'hAxis.maxValue': 'viewWindow.max',
                    'maxValue': new Date(2014, 05, 30), 'minValue': new Date(2014, 04, 05),
                    'viewWindow': { 'max': new Date(2014, 05, 30) },
                },
                'title': chartTitle,
                'chartArea': { 'left': 100, 'top': 100, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 100 },
                'tooltip': { isHtml: true }
            },
            'view': {
                'columns': [{

                    type: 'string',
                    label: data.getColumnLabel(3),
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        var date = new Date(parseInt(dt.getValue(row, 3)));
                        return dateFormatter.formatValue(date);
                    }
                }, 1, {
                    type: 'string',
                    role: 'tooltip',
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                        return 'Name: ' + dt.getValue(row, 0) + ', Decimal Price: ' + +dt.getValue(row, 1) + ', Date: ' + +dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3);
                    }
                }]
            }
        });

        new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('PieChartExample')).bind([categoryPicker], [line]).draw(data);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your DataTable column is type "datetime", you don't want to call `parseInt` on it here:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(dt.getValue(row, 3)));
```

just get the date directly:

```
var date = dt.getValue(row, 3);
```